# cURL POST not working with shell script

Tags: xml, shell, post, curl

I am trying to use cURL POST method to make REST API call from my RHEL system. I am using below request:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --data @file myurl.com
```

However, the data is not getting posted into the target site and showing below status:

> upload completely sent off: 121 out of 121 bytes < HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type < Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 <
> Date: Wed, 19 Aug 2015 13:55:43 GMT < Content-Length: 0 <
>
> Connection #0 to host ---- left intact
>
> Closing connection #0

P.S. I tried with all possible options like passing user:passwd, / changing Content types...with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I could able to POST the request by maintaining content-type as */* and it solved my problem.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to upload a text file you should use this:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --form "fileupload:@file.txt" myurl.com
```

And probably you can also remove the `--header`

Comment: Hello Michelem,  I am using an xml document. I tried all the ways and i am getting the same error..Please let me know how to trouble shoot this.